# Interview question about dependency management

Tags: algorithm, graph

In one of my recent interviews, I was asked about how does a package manager tool like `npm` or `pip` might work internally in terms of figuring out which dependencies to install first.

For instance, say you want to install a package A which depends upon package B, which in turn depends on package C. In such a case, the package C should be installed first followed by B and then A.

The dependency trail can get a lot more complicated which I might believe can be represented in the form of a graph. Now the question is to figure out if there exists a cyclic dependency amongst the packages and if not, then to print the packages in the order in which they should be installed.

I couldn't come up with a correct/optimal solution in time, but maybe someone from here can help?

Thanks!

Comment: Also before installing any module npm first install it's dependency from package.json, if any dependency is already installed then is not installed again.

Comment: @NAVIN they know that npm and pip can do those things. The question is about what algorithm might be used internally to accomplish that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependency between packages can be modeled as a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

A dependency graph is invalid if it contains a cycle, for which you can refer to the following algorithm for detecting a cycle in a directed graph: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/

If there's no cycle in the graph, then you can perform a topological sort to obtain the order in which the dependencies should be installed: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/

Hope this answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would add that cycle detection is very closely related to topological sorting, and it is possible to do both in one pass. I.e. a function that either returns the topological sort of the graph or else indicates that a cycle is present. For example: [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

Please follow [this link of npm algo](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm) for more clarification

**Dependency Resolution**

I am taking the exact example provided in the npm documentation.

Note: From the v3 the dependency resolution algorithm is changed so this example applicable for v3 and above npm versions.

Lets consider the following example :

```
Module-A, depends on Module B v1.0.
Module-C, depends on Module B v2.0.
```

*Note the sequence of modules mentioned because it plays a significant role in the dependency resolution.*

So first is the module A in sequence and it depends on the module B v1.0, npm will install both module A and its dependency, module B, inside the `/node_modules` directory, flat.

[image: Simple Dependency]

Next in the sequence is module C which depends on again module B but with a different version. npm handles this by nesting the new, different, module B version dependency under the module that requires it

[image: Multilevel Dependency]

Now what happens if we install another module that depends on Module B v1.0? or Module B v2.0?

So lets say :

```
Module-D, depends on Module B v2.0.
Module-E, depends on Module B v1.0.
```

Because B v1.0 is already a top-level dependency, we cannot install B v2.0 as a top level dependency. Therefore Module B v2.0 is installed as a nested dependency of Module D, even though we already have a copy installed, nested beneath Module C. Module B v1.0 is already a top-level dependency, we do not need to duplicate and nest it. We simply install Module E and it shares Module B v1.0 with Module A.

[image: Multiple dependency on same package]

Now the interesting part, what happens if we update Module A to v2.0, which depends on Module B v2.0, not Module B v1.0 ?

**The key is to remember that install order matters.**

Even though Module A was installed first (as v1.0) via our `package.json`, using `npm install` command means that Module A v2.0 is the last package installed.

As a result, npm does the following things when we install module A v2.0

```
It removes Module A v1.0.
It installs Modules A v2.0.
It leaves Module Bv1.0 because Module E v1.0 still depends on it.
It installs Module Bv2.0 as a nested dependency under Module A v2.0, since Module B v1.0 is already occupying the top level in the directory hierarchy.
```

Finally, let’s also update Module E to v2.0, which also depends on Module B v2.0 instead of Module B v1.0, just like the Module A update.

npm performs the following things:

```
It removes Module E v1.0.
It installs Module E v2.0.
It removes Module B v1.0 because nothing depends on it anymore.
It installs Module B v2.0 in the top level of the directory because there is no other version of Module B there.
```

[image: More complex dependency]

Now, this is clearly not ideal. We have Module B v2.0 in nearly every directory. To get rid of duplication, we can run:

```
npm dedupe
```

This command resolves all of the packages dependencies on Module B v2.0 by redirecting them to the top level copy of Module B v2.0 and removes all the nested copies.

[image: Same level dependency]

**Conclusion**

So the key take away from this example is that **installation order matters** and that can be ensured only by using npm command while adding or updating any package in the project. There may be possibility the generated dependency tree by npm would be different on different local development machine but it wont affect the behavior of your application because Even though the trees are different, both sufficiently install and point all your dependencies at all their dependencies, and so on, down the tree. You still have everything you need, it just happens to be in a different configuration.

if you want your node_modules directory to be the same than use `npm install` command, when used exclusively to install packages from a `package.json`, will **always produce the same tree**. This is because install order from a `package.json` is **always alphabetical**. Same install order means that you will get the same tree.

You can reliably get the same dependency tree by removing your `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` whenever you make a change to your `package.json`.